# Change slide direction according to pager item clicked (jquery cycle)

Tags: jquery, cycle, carousel

I need some help getting the jquery cycle plugin to work as below:

Basically, I use pager and not left/right buttons. I need to slide from right to left when clicking on a forward pager item and to slide in reverse(from left to right) when clicking on a previous pager item.

My setup is basic, as on http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ .

It might be a simple one but I could not find a way to do it yet.

```
if (jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.cycle)) {
$('.mycarousel').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    pager:  '#titleindicators',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: paginate,
    pause:1,
    timeout: 5000
});
}
 function paginate(ind, el)
{
    return '<a href="#'+ ind +'">&nbsp;</a>';
}
```

I tried using onPagerEvent with no luck:

```
var cs=0;
function onClicky(zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement){
    if(cs-zeroBasedSlideIndex<0){
        $('.mycarousel').cycle({fx: 'scrollLeft'});
    }
    else{
        $('.mycarousel').cycle({fx: 'scrollRight'});
    }
    cs = zeroBasedSlideIndex;
}
```

Otherwise, the plugin works ok but it's really annoying to click on a previous pager item and see it coming in like it's moving forward.

Comment: Of course, from a cyclical point-of-view, it *is* coming from "up ahead".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the fx property to 'scrollHorz' (or 'scrollVert' if you want to move in the vertical direction).

[jquery cycle pager transitions](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager9.html)

[jquery cycle scrollHorz/scrollVert demos](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/scrollhv.html)